# Get the data on foundation reveal modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am trying to search the records with some parameters and get the search result on the reveal modal,i am happily doing with posting the search parameters and getting the data on scope,But not getting the same data on reveal modal.
Here is how i am doing.

my view:

```
<div class="caption" ng-controller="mysearchfilter">
  <form ng-submit="mysearchattempt($event)">      
        <div class="row">

          <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns padding-none">
              <span class="caption-span">I'm serach by</span>
                <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
                  <input ng-model="search.requirements" type="text" placeholder="Internship Keyword">
                </div>

                <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
                  <input ng-model="search.title" type="text" placeholder="Major">
                </div>
          </div>

          <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns padding-none">
            <span class="caption-span left-pad">Location</span>
            <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
              <input ng-model="search.city" type="text" placeholder="City, State, or Zip Code">
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns last-button">
              <button class="button tiny orange-button width-button" type="submit" >
                  <img src="img/search.png" style="width:166px;" >
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
  </form>

      </div>
```

my JS

```
customApp.controller('mysearchfilter',["$scope","CommonServices","toaster",function($scope,CommonServices,toaster){
             $scope.jobsFound=[];
      $scope.greet='hi';
      $scope.mysearchattempt=function(eventP){

        eventP.preventDefault();
        console.log($scope.search);
      CommonServices.saveData($scope.search,'mysearchbox').
        success(function(responseData){
          if(responseData.Success){
            $scope.jobsFound=responseData.Success;

            console.log($scope.jobsFound);
          }
          else if(responseData.Fail){
            toaster.pop('warning','','No Such Jobs Found');
          }
          else {
            toaster.pop('error','','Contact Support');
          }
          $('#myJobs').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        }).
        error(function(responseData){
          toaster.pop('error','','Http Error.');
        });

      }

}]);
```

my modal section.

```
 <div ng-controller="mysearchfilter">
<div id="myJobs" class="reveal-modal xlarge"  data-reveal>
            <div class="form-container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
{{jobsFound}}                
                  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SNo.</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Requirements</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Apply</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="jobs in jobsFound">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.title}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.requirements}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.description}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.City}},{{jobs.state}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.position_required}}</td>
      <td>{{jobs.hours}} , {{jobs.compensation}}</td>
      <td ng-if="jobs.status=='active'"><button class="success">Apply</button></td>
      <td ng-if="jobs.status=='deactive'"><button class="dissabled danger">Expired</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
          </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            <span>2014 &copy; Internbuddy.com,All rights reserved.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="large-6 columns right-part">
            <span>Developed &amp; design by:Intellectual Boot</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

i am getting `jobsFound` scope in console but not on the reveal modal.Pleas suggest me what mistake i am committing.

Comment: i got my answer,in place of $scope ,i user $rootscope.

Comment: Please provide such a plunker link for your code.

Comment: @user284303 a good practice would be to put that data part in a service and then share it. Did you consider removing the getters and setters and stuff from controllers?